# `exitFailure` gives zero exit code

Tags: exit-code, idris

I'd expect [`exitFailure`](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/idris2/current/base_docs/docs/System.html#System.exitFailure)

> Exit the program indicating failure.

to give a non-zero exit code, but the program

```
main : IO ()
main = exitFailure
```

results in

```
$ idris2 Foo.idr -x main
$ echo $?
0
```

What have I misunderstood?

Comment: What happens if you directly execute the the executable instead of using `x`?

Comment: @michaelmesser ah, now that works ... interesting. It's enough for my needs, but I'll leave the question open